# Map Kit cannot find route between two coordinate in USA

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

My code:

```
 let req = MKDirectionsRequest()
    req.source = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()
    req.destination = destination
    let dir = MKDirections(request:req)

if dir.calculating {
    print("calculating")
} else {
    print("Not Calculating")
}
dir.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler() {
    (response:MKDirectionsResponse?, error:NSError?) in
```

When I print error it shows following:

**`Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=1 "Directions Not Available" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Route information is not available at this moment., NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available, MKDirectionsErrorCode=2, MKErrorGEOError=-902}`**

It always throws the error above.

I cannot get what those error keys are:

**MKErrorGEOError = -902**

**MKDirectionsErrorCode=2**

Googled for more info in it couldn't find it.